# Unaffected XP orbs

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a adventure map in which I am using the new 1.10 tag "NoGravity" on XP orbs to make them float around at night on a grassy plain, but they can be affected by a players presence and are pulled towards them, is there any way to make them unaffected by nearby players but still move naturally and be pickup-able?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put XPOrbs on other entities, like invisible armor stands. If you do, orbs will only be pulled towards the player from 1 block range (it's point-blank range, so it should be fine).
You were also talking about orbs moving naturally, but I can't see them move at all. Could you explain it?

Comment: What I meant by that was their natural motion when they are spawned, as I am using the NoGravity tag on them, after they spawn from mob death or such I do not want them to be still entities. so they will, for example still move inside of a designated area, a bit like how a butterfly in a jar can still fly around in a jar, it might not, but it does have that choice. From what you gave me I will make the armor stands do the moving, thanks!